# What is the fastest and average time to attain each badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, data-explorer, statistics

These seem to be interesting questions to understand *in general* how much effort is expended to attain a badge.

Effort is the wrong word, some badges are gained through fortune or uncontrollable chaos. But nevertheless it may be useful to deduce *trends* over time and across tags.

Is there some kind of query to generate statistics for (a) fastest, and/or (b) average time to achieve each badge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the examples for [the Google BigQuery Stack Overflow Dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow) may help answer this.

> This query investigates which gold badges are easier to obtain. It generates the top 10 gold badges, ranked by how many users got them as their first ever gold badges. We also extract how many days it took for these gold badges to be obtained on average.
>
> ```
> #standardSQL
> SELECT badge_name AS First_Gold_Badge,
>        COUNT(1) AS Num_Users,
>        ROUND(AVG(tenure_in_days)) AS Avg_Num_Days
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT
>     badges.user_id AS user_id,
>     badges.name AS badge_name,
>     TIMESTAMP_DIFF(badges.date, users.creation_date, DAY) AS tenure_in_days,
>     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY badges.user_id
>                        ORDER BY badges.date) AS row_number
>   FROM
>     `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.badges` badges
>   JOIN
>     `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.users` users
>   ON badges.user_id = users.id
>   WHERE badges.class = 1
> )
> WHERE row_number = 1
> GROUP BY First_Gold_Badge
> ORDER BY Num_Users DESC
> LIMIT 10
> ```
>
> The results are shown here:
>
> ```
> +------------------+-----------+--------------+
> | First_Gold_Badge | Num_Users | Avg_Num_Days |
> +------------------+-----------+--------------+
> | Famous Question  |    144416 |       1094.0 |
> | Fanatic          |     12992 |        579.0 |
> | Unsung Hero      |     11392 |        555.0 |
> | Great Answer     |      8722 |       1263.0 |
> | Electorate       |      4722 |        769.0 |
> | Populist         |      4631 |       1147.0 |
> | Steward          |       743 |        924.0 |
> | Great Question   |       537 |        684.0 |
> | Copy Editor      |       232 |        533.0 |
> | Marshal          |       136 |        553.0 |
> +------------------+-----------+--------------+
> ```

You can [run the query here](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/savedquery/1057666841514:efc603e1cb8f435c9aa6629a34a34497), and edit it to get exactly the results you want. Registration and login are required, and there's a limited monthly free quota, but it would probably be sufficient for this.

(Disclosure: I currently work at Google, but not in the division responsible for this service.)

Comment: Why not use SEDE for this? No special login, no monthly limit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard SEDE would be a better answer. But I saw this question being downvoted and not getting any help. I didn't feel like putting in the time to find/figure out a SEDE answer, but I had this example on the tip of my tongue from using it earlier this week and figured it was better than nothing. Also: corporate shilling.